# How to export API registries

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I´m currently working with WSO2's API Manager and would like to know how to export APIs created in one instance of the Publisher to a new.

Example:
- User A creates API API_A in instance APIM_A.

I want to be able to copy and see API_A in instance APIM_B.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the registries of both APIM instances you will see APIs in both instances. ACtually this is called clustering. What you have to do is take two publisher nodes and mount their registries.You can check the [guide here](https://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager)